# How can I create API with Django and API REST Framework but based on existing models?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a project with Django and i need to create API REST based on existing models of the project. I mean, is it possible only import the models in the api/v1/models.py ? And i need to use nested serializers but i don't understsand the documentation very well.

---

### UPDATE:

I have a project "hotel" and in the project i have various aplications for example "booking", "panel", "contact" and a lot of more. So, every aplication has models, views, urls.

I need to create API REST based on every models. Now i have created a new aplication with rest-framework named "api" and in the models i only import the models of the other aplications. Basically this is the root of my project.

```
hotel/
     booking/
             __init__.py
             views.py
             models.py
             forms.py
             urls.py
     panel
     contact
     api/ (with rest-framework)
             __init__.py
             models.py
             serializers.py
             urls.py
             views.py
```

> Actually in the api this is the structure:

```
# models.py
from booking.models import ReserveClient, CodeClient, CodeHour


# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import CodeClient, CodeHour

class CodeHourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CodeHour
        fields = (
            'hours', 
            'min_hours',
        )

class CodeClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:
        model = CodeClient
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'code', 
            'date', 
            'max_use', 
            'unique_for_user', 
            'new_client', 
            'message', 
            'comment', 
        )

# views.py
import django_filters
from api.models import CodeClient, CodeHour
from api.serializers import CodeClientSerializer, CodeHourSerializer

class CodeClientFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = CodeClient
        fields = ['code']


class CodeClientList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = CodeClient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CodeClientSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = CodeClientFilter

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Ok, now i want to generate a view with both serializers, because i need response JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 4,
    code: "3hours",
    date: null,
    max_use: 0,
    unique_for_user: true,
    new_client: true,
    menssage: "",
    comment: "",

    hours: "", (CodeHourSerializer)
    min_hours: "", (CodeHourSerializer)
  }
]
```

Hopefully with the code will be easier to understand.

Thanks.

Gustavo.

Comment: Thanks, i gonna update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure your model looks like, but I think you just need to add SerializerMethodField on your CodeClientSerializer.

```
class CodeClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hours = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    min_hours = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = CodeClient
        fields = (
            ...
            'hours', 
            'min_hours',
        )


    def get_hours(self, obj):
        return HOURS # set your value here

    def get_min_hours(self, obj):
        return MIN_HOURS # set your value here
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create API REST base on models of the project

DRF provides a `ModelViewSet` just for that, all you do is tie it to one of your models

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing user instances.
    """
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

> I need to use nested serializers 
>   and for your serializer you can do:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nested_field = MyOtherModelSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: Thanks, but i have this example.